# Android Emulator - Connection Refused

Tags: android, android-emulator, asp.net-apicontroller

I've tried so many different methods and have made no progress.

I'm using: Windows 8.1, VS 2015, VS Emulator for Android, Xamarin Forms, Android 6.0 (API Level 23 - Marshmallow), and IIS v8.5.9600.16384

From the emulator's browser, I can get a response from IIS. But from the app I get `connection refused`.

I've tried disabling my Firewall and AV completely. Tried using PC's machine name, PC's IP address, and 10.0.2.2. Tried ports 80, 56739, 5555, 9999

In Command Prompt (Admin) I ran `netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:%Port%/ user=everyone` for each port (where %port% is the actual port)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application android:label="EventPlanner.Droid"></application>
</manifest>
```

I don't know what else to try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the AndroidManifest file was corrupt even though it opened and appeared just find. I previously ran a clean and rebuild on the entire solution but I ran a clean and rebuild on the Android project and its PCL. Now it works... An entire week lost...

Comment: 'Just' an entire week ...?  That's peanuts .. I've lost DECADES trying to get this twaddle to work